# Process variable names in JSON configuration file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, configuration-files, string-interpolation

So, I am more writing this question to see if something is possible via simpler means than writing my own parser/interpolater.

I have a json configuration block. It should be noted that this block is built from a combination of a file and some pre-determined entry. Let's say it looks like this:

```
{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "$ng serve -poll=1000 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "$ng build --prod --output-hashing=none",
    "build:watch": "$ng build --output-hashing=none --watch",
    "test": "$ng test --single-run",
    "lint": "$ng lint",
    "e2e": "$ng e2e"
    }
}
```

And what I would like to do is everywhere that has the $ng would, dynamically, replace with the value of the ng parameter. That would mean that this version:

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "/some/path/to/ng",
        "start": "$ng serve -poll=1000 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
        "build": "$ng build --prod --output-hashing=none",
        "build:watch": "$ng build --output-hashing=none --watch",
        "test": "$ng test --single-run",
        "lint": "$ng lint",
        "e2e": "$ng e2e"
    }
}
```

would ultimately turn into:

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "/some/path/to/ng",
        "start": "/some/path/to/ng serve -poll=1000 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
        "build": "/some/path/to/ng build --prod --output-hashing=none",
        "build:watch": "/some/path/to/ng build --output-hashing=none --watch",
        "test": "/some/path/to/ng test --single-run",
        "lint": "/some/path/to/ng lint",
        "e2e": "/some/path/to/ng e2e"
    }
}
```

I am just trying to sort out if this is something that can be done in a straightforward fashion (via existing cmdlets), or if it is something I would have to write myself. Also, I should note, this is only an example, and it is possible that multiple variable replacements would be being made.

An equivalent use would be the same mechanism that exists in a spring properties file:

```
hu.ednpoint=https://${serverhost.name}/subscription/event
de.ednpoint=https://${serverhost.name}/consume/event
```

Where the variable name is replaced on the fly.

Comment: `.Replace('$ng', '/some/path/to/ng')` ? Like that?

Comment: Have you investigated the commands already in PowerShell? `Get-Command *json*`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. This is quick and dirty but you could add on to this to hopefully get you going in the right direction.

```
# Take your JSON and convert it to a PS object

$json = '{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "/some/path/to/ng",
    "start": "$ng serve -poll=1000 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "$ng build --prod --output-hashing=none",
    "build:watch": "$ng build --output-hashing=none --watch",
    "test": "$ng test --single-run",
    "lint": "$ng lint",
    "e2e": "$ng e2e"
}}' | ConvertFrom-Json



$ngPath = $json.scripts.ng

foreach ($item in $json.scripts | GM | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" })
{
   $json.scripts.$($item.Name) = $json.scripts.$($item.Name).Replace('$ng', $ngPath)
}

# Convert back to JSON if you want
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

All we are doing is taking the JSON object and converting it to a PowerShell object in order to manipulate it (There are other ways of doing this). We then save the ng property that you want to use. We then loop through all the object members of `scripts`. We then replace every reference of `$ng` with `$ngPath` and we save it back to the `$json` object.

Comment: I made a note. The example I gave is not the best, in that I would like this to work with any (unknown ahead of time) variable names.

Comment: @fitztho I would suggest updating your question with exactly what you're looking for so we can better help you. What I provided does exactly what you initially asked. These new additional details changes the solution quite a bit...